# shell script not working for or condition with -z

Tags: shell

my file name test2.sh.

I was executing the file with ./test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

a="1111"
b=""
if [ -z $b -o -z $a ]
then
echo "a or b is empty"
else
echo "a and b not empty"
fi
```

it always showing a and b not empty in the output.
what's wrong?

And if i use only [ -z $b ], then it's working.

And I have also tried with [ -z $b -o -a $b ] then it's working.

is there any problem with using -o -z simultaneously?

Comment: You should be getting a "too many arguments" error as well, because without quoting your parameter expansion, your command becomes `[ -z -o -z 1111 ]`.  Always quote parameter expansions. Also, never use `-o`; use `||` to join two separate `test` commands as shown by [Ferdinando's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452481/1126841) `[ -z ]` by itself is always true, because `-z` is a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood your question you can try in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="1111"
b=""
if [ -z "$b" ] || [ -z "$a" ]
then
echo "a or b is empty"
else
echo "a and b not empty"
fi
```

The output:

> a="1111" and b="" => a or b is empty
>
> a="" and b="" => a or b is empty
>
> a="" and b="111" => a or b is empty
>
> a="11" and b="22" => a and b are not empty

I hope this helps